# How do you use Google Voice instead of built-in text message with Siri on iPhone4S?

Tags: iphone, sms, siri, google-voice

I would like to use the Google Voice app instead of the built-in Text Messages with Siri on the iPhone 4S.

Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is currently not possible for Siri to use other apps than the ones it already integrates with.

Source: [Daring Fireball](http://daringfireball.net/2011/10/iphone_4s) (paragraph 9, or <kbd>⌘F</kbd> “there are parallels”).